# Crop marks on an existing template to save paper

Tags: crop, calendar

I would like to use the latex code which is available [here](http://psung.blogspot.ch/2009/06/making-your-own-page-day-calendar.html) to create a page a day calendar. My goal would be to get the same result proposed on the link but 
by dividing the sheet of paper in four, i.e. instead of starting a new page after each day, to put four days on each page. By doing so, I hope to avoid wasting too much paper.
My difficulties are:

1. I don't know how to play with the crop marks so well,
2. I am not familiar with using recursive scripts in latex.

Point 1. is actually the main issue but 2. makes it more complicated...

Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is going to be ugly. But here it goes.  We first generate the calendar, then crop it using Heiko's `pdfcrop` and insert the cropped pages using `pdfpages` package. All of these is done in a single file. `calendar.tex` inside the `filecontents*` environment is the actual original calendar file.

```
%% main.tex file

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    %% change paper size
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{calendar.tex}
\documentclass[17pt,oneside,final,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}

\settrims{0in}{0in}

\settrimmedsize{4in}{6in}{*}
\settypeblocksize{3.5in}{1.75in}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.25in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{0.05in}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0.01in}{0.1in}
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0.25in}{3.5in}{0in}

\checkandfixthelayout

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[final]{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\daypage}[6] {%
  \marginpar{\includegraphics[height=3.4in]{#1}}
  \begin{center}
    \Large{#2} \\
    \HUGE{\textbf{#3}} \\
    \large{#4}
    \vspace{0.4in}
    \small{#5}
    \vspace{0.2in}
    \scriptsize{\textit{#6}}
  \end{center}
  \newpage
}%

\begin{document}
  % Cover page
  \marginpar{\includegraphics[height=3.4in]{example-image}}
  \newpage

  \daypage{example-image-a}{Friday}{01}{Jan 2010}{~}{~}
  \daypage{example-image-b}{Saturday}{02}{Jan 2010}{~}{~}
  \daypage{example-image-c}{Sunday}{03}{Jan 2010}{~}{~}
  \daypage{example-image}{Monday}{04}{Jan 2010}{~}{~}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex calendar}

% crop the pdf using Heiko's pdfcrop
\immediate\write18{pdfcrop calendar.pdf croppedcalendaer.pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,delta=0in 0.4in,noautoscale,]{croppedcalendaer.pdf}  %% you may drop noautoscale,
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `--shell-escape`:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape main
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, thanks a lot! I am going to try to understand what you have done and will certainly learn quit a lot!

Comment: @Nre Feel free to ask for clarifications. I am feeling too lazy now to write detailed explanations :) You know, it is saturday late evening here ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did exactly what you told and I get a pdf with 5 pages and one day on each page... Could you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? thanks :)

Comment: @Nre Did you run my code above as such with `--shell-escape` enabled? The  `nup=1x2` option to `\includepdf` puts them as 2 in on.

Comment: I did something wrong before but now everything works fine! Could you just help me to get the margins as before? They started from the edge of the sheet onwards (the image is not complete now...). Thanks a lot for your help, will be able to do an amazing gift :)

Comment: @Nre Remove `noautoscale` from `\includepdf` options.